# Custom select element with only CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to customize a select element with only CSS, found this:

```
<div class="cs_div">
    <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cs_div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("../images/select.png") no-repeat;
  width: 190px;
}
.cs_div select {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: 215px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.cs_div select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

works great, but something on main stylesheet of site adds a "blank space" at bottom of div, in chrome, in firefox this doesn't occur.

chrome:
[image: blank space at bottom, in chrome]

firefox:
[image: no blank space at bottom, in firefox]

already tried `padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;` but not works...

here is a test site with the custom select element: http://eliterosa.bl.ee/activity/

Comment: Please send us the link to the page, because that's not *all* the CSS

Comment: Or please post a jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ManofSnow sorry my mistake, here is: http://eliterosa.bl.ee/activity/
this is a test site.

Comment: @VictorAurélio Add it to your question, please.  Also, how long does it take to load?  I've been waiting ~5 minutes and now I get this: 'Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to eliterosa.bl.ee

Access a cached copy of eliterosa.­bl.­ee/­activity/­'

Comment: @ManofSnow it loads in a few seconds, ~10s

Comment: I just checked it in Chrome in OS X and I don't see the extra space. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: @VictorAurélio, try to set height:29px to cs-div.

Comment: thank you @nevermind this solved the problem, what should i do about the question ? create a answer with your tip ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague but you may be referring to the vertical alignment of the now inline-block div. You just need to use vertical-align: middle; to div#activity-filter-by-outer...

```
#activity-filter-by-outer { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Now that you made the div an inline block it takes up line-height much like other inline elements.

See screen shot:
[image]

Comment: adding `vertical-align: middle;` have only centered the "Show:" label (thank you for this), but doesn't remove de extra space after de the select element here, the @nevermind comment has the solution for the extra space.

Comment: Victor, I see that you updated the code here: http://eliterosa.bl.ee/activity/ to include the vertical align but I don't see the height:29px on .cs-div? Moreover I added that code and didn't see much of a change? Perhaps chrome on my mac is behaving differently than what you are seeing?

Comment: yes, i added `height:29px`  on localhost only, and apparently it's behaving differently on mac osx, see the @Phire comment, for him there's no extra space also, apparently this only occur in windows. I'll see if this occur in chrome on linux after.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way to remove the select arrow from Firefox. The trick is
to use a mix of -prefix-appearance, text-indent and text-overflow.

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

It's pure CSS and requires no extra markup. Tested on Ubuntu and Linux,
latest versions.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/4WVZW/

by: Ricardo Fuhrmann